# puppeteer seleting <select> <option> tag of dropdown

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to log into lyft using puppeteer but having hard time selecting the country code.  Its select element doesn't have any class id and i was able to scroll the whole options but then couldn't find a way to determine when exactly the option which i need comes into user's view port. puppeteer can scan and find the option immediately but can't click on it as its not visible yet.

here is the url https://account.lyft.com/auth?v=riderweb

all i need is to change the country code.

event its option elements contains just the text. it has no value.

```
<select tabindex="-1" aria-label="1. Select phone number country code." class="sc-1esucz9-3 gnZQVn">
  <option value="" disabled="" hidden="">1. Select phone number country code.</option>
  <option>Afghanistan</option>
  <option>Åland Islands</option>
  <option>Albania</option>
  <option>Algeria</option>
  <option>American Samoa</option>
  <option>Andorra</option>
  <option>Angola</option>
  <option>Anguilla</option>
  <option>Antarctica</option>
  <option>Antigua and Barbuda</option>
  <option>Argentina</option>
  <option>Armenia</option>
  <option>Aruba</option>
  <option>Ascension Island</option>
  <option>Australia</option>
  <option>Austria</option>
  <option>Azerbaijan</option>
  <option>Bahamas</option>
  <option>Bahrain</option>
  <option>Bangladesh</option>
  <option>Barbados</option>
  <option>Belarus</option>
  <option>Belgium</option>
  <option>Belize</option>
  <option>Benin</option>
  <option>Bermuda</option>
  <option>Bhutan</option>
  <option>Bolivia</option>
  <option>Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
  <option>Botswana</option>
  <option>Bouvet Island</option>
  <option>Brazil</option>
  <option>British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
  <option>British Virgin Islands</option>
  <option>Brunei</option>
  <option>Bulgaria</option>
  <option>Burkina Faso</option>
  <option>Burundi</option>
  <option>Cambodia</option>
  <option>Cameroon</option>
  <option>Canada</option>
  <option>Cape Verde</option>
  <option>Cayman Islands</option>
  <option>Central African Republic</option>
  <option>Chad</option>
  <option>Chile</option>
  <option>China</option>
  <option>Christmas Island</option>
  <option>Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
  <option>Colombia</option>
  <option>Comoros</option>
  <option>Congo - Brazzaville</option>
  <option>Congo - Kinshasa</option>
  <option>Cook Islands</option>
  <option>Costa Rica</option>
  <option>Cote D'Ivoire</option>
  <option>Croatia</option>
  <option>Cuba</option>
  <option>Cyprus</option>
  <option>Czech Republic</option>
  <option>Denmark</option>
  <option>Djibouti</option>
  <option>Dominica</option>
  <option>Dominican Republic</option>
  <option>Ecuador</option>
  <option>Egypt</option>
  <option>El Salvador</option>
  <option>Equatorial Guinea</option>
  <option>Eritrea</option>
  <option>Estonia</option>
  <option>Ethiopia</option>
  <option>Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
  <option>Faroe Islands</option>
  <option>Fiji</option>
  <option>Finland</option>
  <option>France</option>
  <option>French Guiana</option>
  <option>French Polynesia</option>
  <option>French Southern Territories</option>
  <option>Gabon</option>
  <option>Gambia</option>
  <option>Georgia</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
  <option>Ghana</option>
  <option>Gibraltar</option>
  <option>Greece</option>
  <option>Greenland</option>
  <option>Grenada</option>
  <option>Guadeloupe</option>
  <option>Guam</option>
  <option>Guatemala</option>
  <option>Guernsey</option>
  <option>Guinea</option>
  <option>Guinea-Bissau</option>
  <option>Guyana</option>
  <option>Haiti</option>
  <option>Heard &amp; Mcdonald Islands</option>
  <option>Honduras</option>
  <option>Hong Kong (China)</option>
  <option>Hungary</option>
  <option>Iceland</option>
  <option>India</option>
  <option>Indonesia</option>
  <option>Iran</option>
  <option>Iraq</option>
  <option>Ireland</option>
  <option>Isle of Man</option>
  <option>Israel</option>
  <option>Italy</option>
  <option>Jamaica</option>
  <option>Japan</option>
  <option>Jersey</option>
  <option>Jordan</option>
  <option>Kazakhstan</option>
  <option>Kenya</option>
  <option>Kiribati</option>
  <option>Kuwait</option>
  <option>Kyrgyzstan</option>
  <option>Laos</option>
  <option>Latvia</option>
  <option>Lebanon</option>
  <option>Lesotho</option>
  <option>Liberia</option>
  <option>Libya</option>
  <option>Liechtenstein</option>
  <option>Lithuania</option>
  <option>Luxembourg</option>
  <option>Macau (China)</option>
  <option>Macedonia</option>
  <option>Madagascar</option>
  <option>Malawi</option>
  <option>Malaysia</option>
  <option>Maldives</option>
  <option>Mali</option>
  <option>Malta</option>
  <option>Marshall Islands</option>
  <option>Martinique</option>
  <option>Mauritania</option>
  <option>Mauritius</option>
  <option>Mayotte</option>
  <option>Mexico</option>
  <option>Micronesia</option>
  <option>Moldova</option>
  <option>Monaco</option>
  <option>Mongolia</option>
  <option>Montenegro</option>
  <option>Montserrat</option>
  <option>Morocco</option>
  <option>Mozambique</option>
  <option>Myanmar (Burma)</option>
  <option>Namibia</option>
  <option>Nauru</option>
  <option>Nepal</option>
  <option>Netherlands</option>
  <option>New Caledonia</option>
  <option>New Zealand</option>
  <option>Nicaragua</option>
  <option>Niger</option>
  <option>Nigeria</option>
  <option>Niue</option>
  <option>Norfolk Island</option>
  <option>North Korea</option>
  <option>Northern Mariana Islands</option>
  <option>Norway</option>
  <option>Oman</option>
  <option>Pakistan</option>
  <option>Palau</option>
  <option>Palestinian Territories</option>
  <option>Panama</option>
  <option>Papua New Guinea</option>
  <option>Paraguay</option>
  <option>Peru</option>
  <option>Philippines</option>
  <option>Pitcairn Islands</option>
  <option>Poland</option>
  <option>Portugal</option>
  <option>Puerto Rico</option>
  <option>Qatar</option>
  <option>Reunion</option>
  <option>Romania</option>
  <option>Russian</option>
  <option>Rwanda</option>
  <option>Samoa</option>
  <option>San Marino</option>
  <option>Sao Tome and Principe</option>
  <option>Saudi Arabia</option>
  <option>Senegal</option>
  <option>Serbia</option>
  <option>Seychelles</option>
  <option>Sierra Leone</option>
  <option>Singapore</option>
  <option>Sint Maarten</option>
  <option>Slovakia</option>
  <option>Slovenia</option>
  <option>So. Georgia &amp; So. Sandwich Isl.</option>
  <option>Solomon Islands</option>
  <option>Somalia</option>
  <option>South Africa</option>
  <option>South Korea</option>
  <option>Spain</option>
  <option>Sri Lanka</option>
  <option>St. Barthelemy</option>
  <option>St. Helena</option>
  <option>St. Kitts &amp; Nevis</option>
  <option>St. Lucia</option>
  <option>St. Martin</option>
  <option>St. Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
  <option>St. Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
  <option>Sudan</option>
  <option>Suriname</option>
  <option>Svalbard &amp; Jan Mayen</option>
  <option>Swaziland</option>
  <option>Sweden</option>
  <option>Switzerland</option>
  <option>Syria</option>
  <option>Taiwan</option>
  <option>Tajikistan</option>
  <option>Tanzania</option>
  <option>Thailand</option>
  <option>Timor-Leste</option>
  <option>Togo</option>
  <option>Tokelau</option>
  <option>Tonga</option>
  <option>Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
  <option>Tunisia</option>
  <option>Turkey</option>
  <option>Turkmenistan</option>
  <option>Turks &amp; Caicos Islands</option>
  <option>Tuvalu</option>
  <option>U.S. Outlying Islands</option>
  <option>U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
  <option>Uganda</option>
  <option>Ukraine</option>
  <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
  <option>United Kingdom</option>
  <option>United States</option>
  <option>Uruguay</option>
  <option>Uzbekistan</option>
  <option>Vanuatu</option>
  <option>Vatican City</option>
  <option>Venezuela</option>
  <option>Vietnam</option>
  <option>Wallis &amp; Futuna</option>
  <option>Western Sahara</option>
  <option>Yemen</option>
  <option>Zambia</option>
  <option>Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

let me know if you need anything further information from me.

Comment: I don't see any Puppeteer/Node JS code here. Please [edit] a [mcve] into your question [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen i was able to solve my issue. Above option was the wrong direction. It was not by using the above html tags.  I have posted my answer.

Comment: Glad you worked it out, but the question is still unanswerable to everyone else, so I suggest [edit]ing more context in so it has value to future visitors of the site. I don't see how anyone could reasonably have posted that answer based on the tiny HTML snippet shown here, taken out of larger context, and no foundational code attempt.

Answer (score 0):

After getting lost in the above options for hours. I found a way to select the country. it was not by using above options.

```
const browser = await createBrowser();
const pages = await browser.pages();
page = pages[0];
await page.goto(BASE_URL, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
const flagButton = await page.$("button:has(svg)");
if (flagButton) {
    console.log("flag button found");
    await flagButton.click();
}
const ul = await page.$("ul");
await ul.evaluate((ul) => ul.scrollTo(0, 0));
const divs = await page.$$("div[role='option']");
console.log("divs", divs.length);
let indiaDiv;
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    const div = divs[i];
    const text = await div.getProperty("textContent");
    const textString = await text.jsonValue();
    console.log("textString", textString);
    if (textString.includes("India") && textString.includes("91")) {
        indiaDiv = div;
        break;
    }
}
if (indiaDiv) {
    console.log("india div found");
    await indiaDiv.evaluate((indiaDiv) => indiaDiv.scrollIntoView());
    await indiaDiv.click();
}
```